# Want to move to Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5

I want to move to Laravel. I have knowledge of HTML, CSS, JS, jQuery, PHP, MySQL, CI, WordPress with many years experience. I am intending to move to the latest version of Laravel.

I am using Linux Ubantu 14.04 with PHP and MySQL .

Is any body can guide me the way.  Is there any  good video tutorial or presentation tutorial that help me to learn it.

Comment: Search in the internet. Type **Laravel 5 Tutorial**

Comment: You don't have to ask tutorials here... Internet is availabe... Ask your doubts...

Comment: Thanks, I search in the internet, causing difficulties to create a hello world project in my Ubantu 14.04 laptop. I can not overcome it, trying it for last few days. Just help me to make a hello world project in Laravel. If you have any text or video tutorial which helped you while you learned, please provide me if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a hello world program.

Comment: you can go here https://laracasts.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is hello world program in Laravel

First download and Install laravel:

**Installation**
First run these two steps to install composer in ubuntu
`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
 and
`sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` 
if you dont have curl means do this first
`sudo apt-get install curl`

Then run the following command to install laravel

`composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`

**Note: You need to have PHP before doing all of this**

then do the following command `sudo export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"`.

Then goto your var/www/html directory through terminal. Now just type `laravel new project_name`.

Then goto `app\http\routes.php` add the below. This file is used to define your routes.

`Route::get('helloworld', 'HelloworldController@index');` This means when you goto helloworld page this would ask `index` function in `HelloworldController`.

Then goto root folder via terminal of Laravel then do the following command in terminal. eg: `cd /var/www/html/your_project_name`. Then type the following command.

`php artisan make:controller HelloworldController` this will creates controller name `HelloworldController`.

Then goto `app\http\controller` then you can see `HelloworldController`. Open the controller. then add `use View;` on the top of the controller. This is used to return views.  Then find `function index()` in the HelloworldController. write the below code in that

`return view('helloworld');` this would goto `resources/views/helloworld.blade.php` because the default resource directory is `resources/views`.

The views are located in `resources\views` directory. So goto `resources/views` directory, then create a file name `helloworld.blade.php` because laravel has blade template in default. Just open the file and write "Hello World" then run your laravel application like this `"http://localhost/projectname/public/index.php/helloworld"`

This would return Hello World.

Comment: Thanks Praveen Srinivasan, I want to make you understand that I can not be able to install Laravel here in my Laptop with Ubantu 14.04 is running. Here all other php projects are running fine using url http://localhost/project_name . Can you help me to install it in my Ubantu 14.04 laptop.  Thanks

Comment: Finally I installed laravel. But when I run " php artisan serve"  Then an error message comes. it is Could not open input file: artisan.    Also  "laravel new blog"  is not running. It giving the error laravel: command not found. What should be the URL.
  ** Please help me **

Comment: you have to run `sudo export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"` this command to get laravel command run.